# Rcpp could not be loaded

Tags: r, rcpp

Any idea why I keep getting the message below in R?

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rcpp', details:
    call: .External("class__dummyInstance", ...)
    error: C symbol name "class_dummyInstance" not in load table
Error: package 'Rcpp' could not be loaded
```

I have tried everything and it seems that nothing can fix this problem. The machine used is not mine but a client's. There are a lot of restrictions from IT and they have roaming profiles. I installed the 32-bit and 64-bit, just the 32-bit and just the 64-bit but nothing. The machine has Windows 7 64-bit.

So any ideas?

Comment: The `k` in `ckass__dummyInstance` is suspicious. Also is this `class_dummyInstance` with only one underscore. It just seems that Rcpp was not correctly built.

Comment: Sorry I typed this from the remote machine as I couldn't copy the text. It should be class_dummyInstance.

Comment: Ah. This is a bug in Rcpp, signaled [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/147).

Comment: Interesting, will fix.  Now what tickled the bug here, ie why has not been an issue before?

Comment: I still don't understand how this could be tickled at loading without invoking the actual member function that had the bug.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel see https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/66540c24bbde6ef995362be3676f66e7455bd166/R/zzz.R#L22

Comment: @RomainFrancois Why did it bit this OP and not everybody else?

Comment: Thanks Dirk. Still cannot understand how nobody else spotted this before.

Comment: Any idea when you will make an official or dev release Dirk?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `Rcpp` that calls this registered symbol as if it was not. The problem is the definition of [new_dummyObject](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/b5ff9b5530e4a82682caab5ddc87ac23a7b8857e/R/Module.R#L128):

```
new_dummyObject <- function(...)
    .External( "class__dummyInstance", ...)
```

should be

```
new_dummyObject <- function(...)
    .External( class__dummyInstance, ...)
```

I submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/147).

Comment: Thanks for this. Any idea when you will be able to release a new build? Even if it's a dev release?